# Retrieve data from database column in WebMatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webmatrix

Im using WebMatrix 2. I need retrieve data from column in my database. This is database column:

[image]

I have used this code to retrieve data and get it in combobox

```
@{
var db1 = Database.Open("StarterSite");
var selectCommand = "SELECT Motivo FROM Set_Residenziali";
var selectedData = db1.Query(selectCommand); 
}

<select name="motivo">
    @foreach(var row in selectedData)
    {
        <option value="@row.Motivo">@row.Motivo</option>
    }
</select>
```

With this code I get this result:

[image]

But I need obtain this result:

[image]

I tried many solutions, without success. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the value:

```
<select name="motivo">
    @foreach(var row in selectedData){
        foreach(var item in row.Motivo.ToString().Split(new [] {','})){
        <option>@item</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```